# LINQ expression could not be translated

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following database query where I am trying to check if there exists an item with a particular barcode that is linked to a particular mailbag. The query is as follows:

```
var exists = await dbcontext.Items
                .Include(t => t.MailBagItems)
                .ThenInclude(mt => mt.MailBag)
                .AnyAsync(t => t.Barcode.Equals(barcode) &&
                t.MailBagItems.FirstOrDefault() != null && 
t.MailBagItems.FirstOrDefault().MailBag.Number.ToLower().Equals(mailbagNumber.ToLower()));
```

For some reason, I'm getting the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression could not be
>   translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,
>   or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to
>   either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or
>   ToListAsync().

I know for a fact from removing parts of the boolean expression that the issue is in the last boolean condition where I'm checking the mailbag number. However, I get the same error if I remove the calls to ToLower(). Can someone indicate what is wrong with my expression and how to fix it? Please note I'm using .NET core 3 and SQL Server.

Comment: If you're using Sql Server then odds are that you don't need the ToLower calls since strings are compared case insensitively unless you've got a case sensitive collation. I don't know if EF translates ToLower. I'm also not sure about Equals but you may want to try == instead

Comment: try `string.Equals(t.MailBagItems.FirstOrDefault().MailBag.Number,mailBagNumber,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried all of your suggestions and the error is still the same.

Comment: you have many misunderstanding in your query,
try this and let me know the result to describe it in detail:
`var lowerNumber = mailbagNumber.ToLower();

var exists = await dbcontext.Items
                .AnyAsync(t => t.Barcode == barcode &&
t.MailBagItems.First().MailBag.Number.ToLower() == lowerNumber));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to make the query work by changing it to the following:

```
var exists = dbcontext.Items
                .AnyAsync(t => t.Barcode.Equals(barcode) &&
                            t.MailBagItems.Any(t => t.MailBag.Number.ToLower().Equals(mailbagNumber.ToLower())));
```

Seems it wasn't enjoying the .FirstOrDefault().MailBag before.

Comment: Did you just use trial and error to figure this out? I am having the same issue and it worked in .NET Core v2.2, but now that we've upgraded to v3.1 we're seemingly needing to updating a bunch of Linq expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Your `AnyAsync` is to complex for EF to transform to SQL, if you want to still use that query you will have to materialize the entities first, like this:

```
var exists = dbcontext.Items
                .Include(t => t.MailBagItems)
                .ThenInclude(mt => mt.MailBag)
                .ToListAsync()
                .AnyAsync(t => t.Barcode.Equals(barcode) &&
                t.MailBagItems.FirstOrDefault() != null && 
t.MailBagItems.FirstOrDefault().MailBag.Number.ToLower().Equals(mailbagNumber.ToLower()));
```

Also you are missing the `await` keyword,  or was that intended?

Comment: had to change your ```.ToListAsync().AnyAsync``` to ```.ToListAsync().Result.Any``` but it works otherwise so thank you. I ommitted the await by mistake when I copied it into the question